# Cluster Access Issue in Azure Using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

Error: authentication is not configured for provider. Please configure it through one of the following options: 1. DATABRICKS_HOST + DATABRICKS_TOKEN environment variables. 2. host + token provider arguments. 3. azure_databricks_workspace_id + AZ CLI authentication. 4. azure_databricks_workspace_id + azure_client_id + azure_client_secret + azure_tenant_id for Azure Service Principal authentication. 5. Run `databricks configure --token` that will create ~/.databrickscfg file.

Please check and Advice about this error

Comment: please provide code that creates this issue and more information on how Databricks provider is configured...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below workaround given in this [***github***](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/372) discussion to troubleshoot your issue

- Overall recommendation is to also separate workspace creation (azurerm provider) and for workspace provisioning (databricks provider).
- the other workaround is to have an empty `~/.databrickscfg` file, so locals block might be avoided. not ideal, but will work..
- you can also managed to work around it by using locals to pre-configure related resource names and then reference those when building the workspace resource id in the provider config

[image]

and databricks provider resources all have a `depends_on` block with the databricks workspace